# cvxpy is solving to produce empty answer

Tags: python, python-3.8, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am working with the following code:

```
import sys, numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sims = np.random.randint(20, 30, size=500)
    center = 30
    n = [500, 1]

    # minimize     p'*log(p)
    # subject to
    #              sum(p) = 1
    #              sum(p'*a) = target1

    A = np.mat(np.vstack([np.ones(n[0]), sims]))
    b = np.mat([1.0, center]).T

    x = cvx.Variable(n)
    obj = cvx.Maximize(cvx.sum(cvx.entr(x)))
    constraints = [A @ x == b]
    prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)
    prob.solve()
    weights = np.array(x.value)
```

Here the `x.value` is empty. I am not sure how to modify my above setup. I am trying to readjust the mean of `sims` to a different value defined by variable `center` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to check if `prob.value` is finite before trying to access the values of the variables after calling `prob.solve()`. As you have a maximization problem, and `prob.value` returns `-inf` *(see below output)*, it means that your problem is infeasible:

```
import sys, numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sims = np.random.randint(20, 30, size=500)
    center = 30
    n = [500, 1]

    # minimize     p'*log(p)
    # subject to
    #              sum(p) = 1
    #              sum(p'*a) = target1

    A = np.mat(np.vstack([np.ones(n[0]), sims]))
    b = np.mat([1.0, center]).T

    x = cvx.Variable(n)
    obj = cvx.Maximize(cvx.sum(cvx.entr(x)))
    constraints = [A @ x == b]
    prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)
    prob.solve()
    print(prob.value)
    weights = np.array(x.value)
```

Output:

```
-inf
```

---

From [Variable values return 'None' after solving the problem](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/issues/924#issuecomment-575852563):

> Diagnosing infeasibility issues is a common task when using optimization models in practice. Usually you will find either a bug in your code, or you will see that the abstract mathematical model can be infeasible (even if coded up perfectly).

For a quick reference of how it just might be how your abstract mathematical model is infeasible, rather than a bug in your code, you can try either replacing the

```
constraints = [A @ x == b]
```

with

```
constraints = [A @ x >= b] # Outputs 183.9397...
```

or with

```
constraints = [A @ x <= b] # Outputs 6.2146...
```

and you will see that your code works.

Answer (score 1):

First in way of debugging:
try and use this to see what is the issue:

```
prob.solve(verbose=True)
```

and this to check that a solution was found:

```
print(prob.status)
```

In your case the problem is infeasible, the linear problem you are trying to solve - doesn't always have a solution. You may introduce an "eps" variable to define the needed accuracy for your problem, or test in advance using a linear algebra library that some solution exists.